# Add click event to all 'a' tags in main menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#MainMenu a").click(function () {
                $("#divContent").load( ???? );
            });
        });
```

I want to retrieve all links from my main menu, attach `click` events to them, and tell jQuery to load some content to `#divContent` via ajax call. Content location should depend ofcourse on `href` tag in each link.

Comment: No. I want exaclty what you show me in ur answer, but now I';m trying to run this. Had it almost working, but now it;'s dead. Need something like debbugger for JS ;P Because I dont know what events are registered, and whats goes wrong.

Comment: You can debug by putting `debugger;` in your js code and use browser console, like in Chrome/win you can use f12 to open up developer console.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are almost there, Try:

```
 $("#MainMenu a").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault(); //prevent the default click behavior of the anchor.
     $("#divContent").load(this.href); //just get the href of the anchor tag and feed it onto load.
 });
```

Comment: Don't forget to `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @BillCriswell Spot on... !!

Comment: Dang. Works in chrome. But not in Opera... 10 minutes ago it worked in Opera too, but not now... hmm maybe I will restart Windows and try again.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for performance as well and you have a large list of options the best approach would be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $('#MainMenu').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var $a = $(this);
         $("#divContent").load($a.prop('href'));
     });

});
```